# Angular 4 ng-controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am building an Asp.net website with Angular 4 and bootstrap. Being a .net developer, I would like to have all the html in the .cshtml files. Earlier I have used Angular 1.0 version and we use the ng-controller and all the services call will be made from there. Trying to find documentation on using controllers but couldn't find any? Do we have ng-controllers in Angular 4? If not whats the best alternative. Also I dont want to use "TemplateUrl" in the component to render the cshtml content. In few cases, cshtml will have dynamic content and don't want an additional http request made.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats right what Usman told you. At Angular 2/4 your App structure is completly new. You got a Template which is controlled by the @Component, where is linked with the attribute: **'template: "Page.html"'**. There is also the **templateURL** Which is also an attribute of @Component. Use this if you want to specify your templateURL in your Typescript File. And another thing: Your Scope has changed a bit so think about it if you try to call javascript code in your template.

hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ng-controllers in Angular 2/4. You have components (kind of, but not exactly, controllers in AngularJs). There is no clean way of using server side views with Angular 2/4 unless you want to use server side rendering of Javascript using nodejs.

Have a look at this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

This is based on [Microsoft's JavaScript services library](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) which does server side compilation for cshtml files. Steve Sanderson has a nice [post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) (though a bit older now) about setting up Angular with ASP.NET

hope this helps.